# Texture Atlas issue

Tags: uv, image, texture-baking

I'm new here, and I've run into a small issue.  I've been working on a racing game in Unity and I use texture atlases to keep my materials at a minimum.  However, I opened up one of the track files today and found this.

[image]

It should look like this

[image]

This was working fine before, and none of my other track files have this issue.  I don't think I'm missing any texture files.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you moved and files about?

Comment: I guess I did, because the UV editor didn't remember my texture atlas.  I re-added it to the model, and it's good to go now.  Thanks!